# How can I add a function that all Razor Pages can access?

Tags: asp.net-core, global, razor-pages

Using Razor Pages ASP.Net Core, I have some functions that I'd like to use on every page. I guess this used to be done with App_Code, but that no longer seems to work in Core. How can I accomplish this in Asp.Net Core Razor Pages?

Comment: would Service Injection work for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-injection

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Option 1 - [DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

1 - Create the service class with the relevant functionality

```cs
public class FullNameService
{
    public string GetFullName(string first, string last)
    {
        return $"{first} {last}";
    }
}
```

2- Register the service in startup

```cs
services.AddTransient<FullNameService>();
```

3- Inject it to the razor page

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly FullNameService _service;

    public IndexModel(FullNameService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public string OnGet(string name, string lastName)
    {
        return _service.GetFullName(name, lastName);
    }
}
```

### Option 2 - [Base Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base)

1- Create a base page model with the function

```cs
public class BasePageModel : PageModel
{
    public string GetFullName(string first, string lastName)
    {
        return $"{first} {lastName}";
    }
}
```

2- Derive other pages from the base model

```cs
public class IndexModel : BasePageModel
{
    public string OnGet(string first, string lastName)
    {
        return GetFullName(first, lastName);
    }
}
```

### Option 3 - [Static Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

1- Use a static function that can be accessed from all pages

```cs
public static class FullNameBuilder
{
    public static string GetFullName(string first, string lastName)
    {
        return $"{first} {lastName}";
    }
}
```

2- Call the static function from the razor page

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string OnGet(string first, string lastName)
    {
        return FullNameBuilder.GetFullName(first, lastName);
    }
}
```

### Option 4 - [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

1- Create an extension method for a specific type of objects (e.g. string)

```cs
public static class FullNameExtensions
{
    public static string GetFullName(this string first, string lastName)
    {
        return $"{first} {lastName}";
    }
}
```

2- Call the extension from razor page

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string OnGet(string first, string lastName)
    {
        return first.GetFullName(lastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add one more solution

### Option 5 - inheritance

1. Define generic class which inherits from `RazorPage<TModel>`

   public abstract class MyBasePage : RazorPage
2. Make all view inheriting from it in `_ViewImports.cshtml`

   @inherits MyBasePage
3. Define methods (an other members) in the class (protected accessibility is enough) an use them from CSHTML

e.g.

definition

```
protected string? PageClass { get => ViewData["PageClass"] as string; set => ViewData["PageClass"] = value; }
```

usage

```
@{
    Title = "Error";
}
```

or

```
<head>
    <title>@Title</title>
```