# ASP.NET CORE Global Method How To/Best Practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, global

I am new to the ASP.NET Core framework (using 3.1 btw) and on several of my pages (each page inherits the `PageModel` class) I have this method defined:

```
private string GetSignedInUser()
{
    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var theUser = claim.Value;
    return theUser;
}
```

I feel it is bad practice of duplicating this method on several of my pages. There are 11 pages in total.

My question is to make this a global method (even if this is possible) is to make a separate class (e.g. `GetCurrentUser`) and then use dependency injection in "Startup.cs" of something like...

```
services.AddScoped(GetCurrentUser)();
```

Do I have the right understanding here? Is this a best practice to follow in the ASP.NET Core world?

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: why not use inheritance and create your own base controller?

Comment: Thanks! I actually never thought of doing that. I overlooked that - must of been buried deep in my coding.

Comment: You could also turn that into an extension method on the User class which makes it available in places other than your pagemodel as well.

Comment: @t.karalis - when you say User class do you mean in my suggestion of creating a class name "GetCurrentUser" or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a function that all Razor Pages can access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158712/how-can-i-add-a-function-that-all-razor-pages-can-access)

Comment: @LazZiya - this is another great solution. I am surprise I haven't found this in my search results before I asked my question.  This works as well. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome @PED :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to potentially create an extension method. You would **not** inject this class via DI.

```cs
public static class UserExtensions
{
    public static string GetCurrentUserName(this User user)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;

        var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        return claim.Value;
    }
}
```

It can be used as:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething()
{
    //do other stuff;

    var currentUserName = User.GetCurrentUserName();

    //do other stuff;
}
```

Comment: @PED If the answer works for you feel free to accept it ;)

Comment: Thank you for typing up a mock up of how to do this. Looking it over it now very clear what to do on my side. Thanks again @t.karalis.

Comment: @t.karalis in .Net6 can we do the same? i get error when add `ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;`

Comment: What error do you get? I haven't used this with .NET 6 but as far as I know that code hasn't changed.